# Does "withhold doing" mean the same as "withhold from doing"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> "The company withhold producing this cell phone."
>
> or
>
> "The company withhold from producing this cell phone."?

Should the verb withhold always come with "from"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your sentences is idiomatic.

1. > The company withhold from producing this cell phone.

   *Withhold* is not used intransitively in contemporary English. [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio102murruoft#page/220/mode/2up), s.v. **Withhold, c.** calls the intransitive usage, with the sense ‘refrain’, obsolete, and gives citations only from 1650–1817. Most of these are uncomplemented or take a *from*+nominal or gerund complement, e.g.

   > **1807** .. No man should withhold from extending his hand to support the fallen.

   But the last citation employs an infinitive complement:

   > **1817** .. He was incapable of giving, or capable of withholding to give .. an opinion.
2. > The company withhold producing this cell phone.

   There are several transitive uses, but none having the sense ‘refrain from, fail to perform’ You will occasionally encounter *withhold* in the sense ‘restrain’ employed reflexively; sometimes this takes a *from* complement; the object of *from* may be a noun phrase or a gerund clause/phrase. *OED 1* gives an example:

   > **1897** .. Blake, .. though tempted, yet withheld himself from yielding.
3. Transitive use in the same ‘restrain’ sense is not yet quite obsolete: The Agent *restrains* some person *from* an action:

   > **1912** .. Walpole .. withheld Great Britain from giving support .. to .. Frederick William.
4. But in contemporary English the only use  of *withhold* I ever encounter is transitive with the sense ‘hold [some desired object] back’*from* some person who otherwise would expect or be entitled to receive it.

   > Employers are required to withhold a portion of an employee's wage for taxes.
   >   The mayor's decision was withheld from the public until his staff could come up with an acceptable explanation.

You may be confusing *withhold* with *withdraw from*, meaning ‘cease to pursue’ some anticipated action:

> The company has withdrawn from producing this cell phone: market research suggested it would not be competitive.

Or *refrain* or *refuse* or *postpone* may be appropriate verbs in this context, depending on what exactly you mean.

Comment: Maybe my sample sentence is not a good one. What I mean is withhold in the sense of refuse. This might be a better example: A inform B on C but withhold (from) informing her on D. 1) Is it correct to use withhold in that sense. 2) is "form" necessary?

Comment: @user226537 *Withhold from* in this sort of context is **obsolete** -- see §1 in my answer. In the context you describe *A **refrain** from informing B about D* is probably best--it leaves open the question of whether B knows that she is not being informed. *A **refuse** to inform B about D* would be used if B asked A to inform her and A explicitly told her they would not.

Comment: Thanks. I asked a related question that I would like to know your view on it.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383808/does-refrain-mean-the-same-as-intentionally-refrain